# request.referrer constantly returns None

Tags: python, flask, request, referrer

The site is written in flask. I start a thread to publish messages in the topic mqtt. The flow function should only be executed when the user is on the profile page. To do this, I use the context of the request `request.referrer`. When you go to other pages, the value of the `request.referrer` remains `None`.
I need the flow function to complete when navigating to another page.
Function of thread:

```
 def handle_publish(self, topic_req_res, m_req_state, qos_req, timer):
    exit_thread = False
    while exit_thread is False:
        with app.test_request_context():
            print(request.referrer)
            if request.referrer is not None:
                if self.profile_url not in request.referrer:
                    exit_thread = True
                    mqtt._disconnect()
                    print("exit")
        print("Send")
        msg = json.dumps(m_req_state)
        mqtt.publish(topic_req_res, msg, qos_req)
        socketio.sleep(timer)
```

Comment: If I remember correctly, it doesn't work on `localhost`

Comment: If I use ```request.referrer``` in the profile page handler, then this gives the correct answer - the address from which they went to the profile page. But as soon as I use this construction in a separate file, in a separate class, and not in the views file, it returns only  ```None```.

Comment: In localhost it works.
Or do you mean that it is the '''with app.test_request_context():''' construction that does not work on the local host?

Comment: No, I remember that I had the same issue (referrer is None) and ended up ignoring it since I found out that only localhost is affected. Sorry if this doesn't help.